# How to print the most times a char occurs from a counter in python

Tags: python, counter

```
Counter(str)
print max(Counter(str))
```

When this prints, it will print the letter in the string that occurs the most, I want to print how many times it occurs not what letter. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: `max(Counter(str))` does not actually do what you think it does. The counter's keys are ordered lexicographically and the max is taken

Answer (score 3):

The `collections.Counter` object already provides a method for this - [`most_common`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common):

> Return a list of the `n` most common elements and their counts from
>   the most common to the least. If `n` is omitted or `None`,
>   `most_common()` returns all elements in the counter. Elements with
>   **equal counts** are ordered **arbitrarily**

*Emphasis mine*

```
print Counter(my_str).most_common(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

A counter behaves like a dictionary, so this works:

```
max(Counter(s).values())
```

Comment: Don't use `str` as your variable, because
`str` is a type in Python.